# How to properly credit yourself/others for design work on a portfolio site?

Tags: designers, portfolio, collaboration

I'm working on a portfolio site to showcase some of my design/layout/photography work. In a lot of cases, myself and one other person would work on a design idea; but in all cases, I am the one doing the assembly work on the computer and tweaking it to completion.

What is the best way to handle credits on a portfolio website when more than one person is involved? There are a few scenarios that I need to properly credit for:

1. Where the other person comes to me with a mostly formed idea; I assemble it on the computer and take a few small liberties on the design (would've taken more, but the other person is a control freak).
2. Where the other person and I are fairly equal in the design; but I execute it on the computer.
3. Where the other person pitched the idea, but I brainstormed/assembled the design and executed it myself on the computer.

Comment: Not a full answer, but for 1-2 I might just say something like "worked/designed/authored in part with ________" or maybe something slightly more specific depending on what it is. For 3 I likely wouldn't mention them at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure there is one best way to do this, but here's an approach:

Generally, with each item/project you could mention a line

`Team project. 
 Members involved:[name][name][myself]
 My role(s):[yadayada]`

As for your specific types of scenarios:

1. Don't go into too specific details, but describe what you did simply. As for the small additions to design, you could litterally that call it that. Or not mention it if otherwise it's not really worth it and they were small additions.
2. You could say you 'co-designed' it and did the 'design realization'. If that's appropriate wording.
3. Mention you did concept and design; who pitched it has nothing to do with that really. Of course you could mention it separately if you should so choose to describe every team member's role in the project.

However, I'm not sure everybody would like to be mentioned on your website, do take their privacy into account.

Comment: Hey Poepje! Thank you so much for your thoughtful input. I think I'm going to go in this direction. Thanks again for taking the time. This topic has been racking my brain, so I appreciate your thoughts. Take care!

Comment: You're welcome, hope it works out for you :)